# Can I view field history tracking for the documents object?

Tags: document, field-history

I cannot find the object to create a report type.

I'd like to track the who changed / replaced a document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no field history tracking on `Document`

Source: [comment thread on above answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107626/can-i-view-field-history-tracking-for-the-documents-object#comment147831_107629)

Answer (score 1):

You can query this information using Workbench. Go to workbench.developerforce.com/query.php and login using your Salesforce credentials. Go to the SOQL query option and enter in the following:

SELECT ContentType,Description,Id,Keywords,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name,Type FROM Document

You could also use a WHERE condition to limit results like:
SELECT ContentType,Description,Id,Keywords,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name,Type FROM Document WHERE Name = EnterNameofDocument

When you have the results, copy and paste the LastModifiedById after the / directly after .com in your browser and you will be taken to the user record of the user that made the change. For example if in my address bar I had the following: https://c.cs14.salesforce.com/apex/test2?id=001E000000nVLHM and my id in the lastModifiedById was 005E0000000d2EPIAY, then I would replace the address bar value with https://c.cs14.salesforce.com/005E0000000d2EPIAY.

Comment: i.e. there is no fieldhistory tracking on `Document`

Comment: @crop1645 Yes there is no fieldhistory, but if that person was the last person to change it then someone could query it with the lastmodifiedbyid field in Workbench. Maybe the audit trail would capture that info as well?

Comment: your answer is a good one - just that OP was about fieldHistory and your solution looked at `lastModifiedById` - my comment, perhaps poorly phrased, was to try and tie back to the OP. "i.e" == "that is to say"

Comment: @crop1645 I get what you're saying :) I was so busy trying to find a possible alternative that I didn't answer the base question. You have WAY more SFDC knowledge than I have. I'm trying to get there.